# Is it possible to manually rollback the database in the Rails console when NOT starting in sandbox mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, transactions, console, rollback

Say you're working in the console, and you delete a record where you have a

```
belongs_to :model :dependent => :destroy
```

where you didn't mean to, for example, and you end up deleting other records as a result of your error.

Is it possible to manually issue a command to rollback the database to the state before your console (or before the command), if you did not start with the -sandbox flag (because you meant to make permanent changes but accidentally made an error)?

In my particular environment, I use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. You don't mention what DBMS you are using but generally once the transaction has been committed or if the query was not wrapped in a transaction, immediately, then you cannot rollback or recover the data.

You should restore the lost data from a backup, if possible.

Comment: Sorry about that; I updated the question–I'm using PostgreSQL.